# linecache.getline and how to loop to the next line

Tags: python, loops, getline

I have this code doing a loop

```
file.write('' + linecache.getline('support_files/sub_page_top_links.txt', 1) + '')
```

It gets the first line in the text file, but, the next time the script loops I need it to get line 2, then the next time the script loops I need it to get line 3, etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a counter and increment it, so:

```
i = 1

file.write('' + linecache.getline('support_files/sub_page_top_links.txt', i) + '')
i += 1
```

Then the next time it will get line 2, etc.

However, if what you want is sequential access, linecache is not the best way to so it. Just open the file and iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

The `linecache` is used for random access lines from a file.

if you just want to loop over lines in a file, you can use,

```
with open('filename') as f1:
   file.write('' + f1.readline() + '')
```